# How does Conv2Plus1D reduces the number of paramateres?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, convolution

Based on [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/video/video_classification) tutorial, and the

> An advantage of this approach is that factorizing the convolutions into spatial and temporal dimensions saves parameters.

statement, the Conv2Plus1D must have fewer parameters than a Conv3D layer. I compared the number of parameters between a Conv2Plus1D and a Conv3D layer and the Conv3D layer had much fewer parameters (around 1/3 of the Conv2Plus1D) than a Conv3D layer.

Am I missing something? Or am I misunderstanding something?
Please clarify if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.11248v3.pdf) that proposed the idea of (2+1)Convolutions, it seems that the `Conv2Plus1D` implementation of the tutorial is *partially* incorrect.

By citing the paper (section 3.5):

> [...] full 3D convolutions may be more conveniently approximated by a 2D convolution followed by a 1D convolution, decomposing spatial and temporal modeling into two separate steps.

So they assume a 3D conv, with an $N\times t\times d\times d$ kernel (where $t$ is the timesteps, and $d$ the depth), can be "factorized" into space and time components by two convolutions: one is $N\times 1\times d \times d$ with $M$ filters, and the other has a $M\times t\times \times 1$ kernel with $N$ filters. The former is the spatial convolution, and the latter is the temporal one.

Now:

> The **hyperparameter** $M$ determines the dimensionality of the intermediate subspace.

They provide a formula to compute $M$:
$$M_i = \frac{td^2 N_{i-1}N_i}{d^2 N_{i-1} + tN_i},$$
where $i$ is the layer index. Basically, with such a formula they choose $M$ so that:

> [...] the number of parameters in the (2+1)D block is **approximately equal** to that implementing full 3D convolution.

In short, the first conv in `Conv2Plus1D` should have $M_i$ filters, and the second conv $N_i$ filters (i.e., the number you would use for the regular 3D conv.). Indeed, can be that $M_i = N_i$ as in the tutorial but that won't follow the paper. Now, if you compute $M_i$ according to the eq. you'll get approximately the same overall number of parameters compared to a full 3D conv. But you can set it as you wish, thus also reducing the #parameters if you want to do so.

Comment: Appreciate the time. I also thought the same thing as I read the paper but because the tutorial was on TensorFlow's own website, I got the sense that I might be missing something. Anyways, thanks for the help.